# Binary search in lisp with higher level function

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, binary-search

I am trying to write a (higher order function) which takes a vector and a function and makes a binary search accroding to that function, i.e. if it returns -1, we need to go lower, for 1 -- higher, for 0 we found the right place.
I came up with something like this, but it seems that I did something wrong with passing function as an argument:

```
(defun bin-search (ls fpred)
 (let ((l (length ls))
       (x (aref ls (floor (length ls) 2))))
       (labels (binsearch (ls fpred l m)
                (case (funcall #'fpred (aref ls m))
                 (-1 (binsearch (ls fpred l (floor (- m l) 2))))
                 (0 (return-from binsearch m))
                 (1 (binsearch (ls fpred m (+ m (floor (- m l) 2)))))))
 (binsearch ls fpred 0 l))))
```

Compiler says that variable FPRED is defined but never used. What is wrong?

Comment: You have some typos `seacrh` vs `search`, and I don't think you have the `labels` syntax right.

Comment: Wow I m so tired I didn't notice. But is everything okay in general?

Comment: Fixed it, didn't change much

Comment: Why did you add `#'`?

Comment: well I thought it to be the syntax of funcall.
If I remove it the error stil persists though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(defun bin-search (ls fpred)
```

Please use meaningful names, you have many short names or abbreviations, which is difficult to read. For example, `ls` makes me think of a list, which could be simply named `list`, but apparently you are working with vectors, so maybe `vec` or `vector`?

```
 (let ((l (length ls))
       (x (aref ls (floor (length ls) 2))))
```

If you want to reuse the length `l` defined in the same let, you can use a `let*` instead, and write `l` instead of the second occurrence of `(length ls)`.

```
       (labels (binsearch (ls fpred l m)
```

The syntax for labels is a **list** of bindings `(name (<args>) <body>)`, so you need to add another pair of parentheses, like `(labels ((binsearch (<args>) <body>)) ...`

Addditionally, you do not need to pass `fpred` as a parameter, it does not change from one invocation of `binsearch` to another. You can just refer to `bin-search`'s `fpred` parameter from inside your local function.

```
                (case (funcall #'fpred (aref ls m))
```

When you write `#'fpred`, which is equivalent to `(function fpred)`, you are looking for `fpred` in the *function namespace*. Here you want to access the function associated with the *variable* named `fpred`, and so you can drop the `#'` part.

```
                 (-1 (binsearch (ls fpred l (floor (- m l) 2))))
```

When you write `(binsearch (ls fpred ...))`, that means: *call `binsearch` with one value, obtained by calling function `ls` with arguments `fpred`, ...*. Parentheses are significant, and you need to remove them here.

```
                 (0 (return-from binsearch m))
                 (1 (binsearch (ls fpred m (+ m (floor (- m l) 2)))))))
 (binsearch ls fpred 0 l))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed (supposedly) everything, it works now. Thanks a lot.

```
(defun bin-search (vec fpred)
 (let* ((l (length vec)))
  (labels ((binsearch (vec l m)
            (case (funcall fpred (aref vec m))
             (-1 (binsearch vec  l (+ l (floor (- m l) 2))))
             (0 (return-from binsearch m))
             (1 (binsearch vec m (+ m (floor (- m l) 2)))))))
     (binsearch vec 0 (floor l 2)))))
```

Improved:

- `let` instead of `let*`
- name of the internal function changed
- `return-from` is not needed

applied:

```
(defun bin-search (vec fpred)
  (let ((l (length vec)))
    (labels ((bin-search-aux (vec l m)
               (case (funcall fpred (aref vec m))
                 (-1 (bin-search-aux vec l (+ l (floor (- m l) 2))))
                 ( 0 m)
                 ( 1 (bin-search-aux vec m (+ m (floor (- m l) 2)))))))
      (bin-search-aux vec 0 (floor l 2)))))
```

- `let` replaced by `&aux` arg -> one indentation level less
- `vec` does not need to be passed

applied:

```
(defun bin-search (vec fpred &aux (l (length vec)))
  (labels ((bin-search-aux (l m)
             (case (funcall fpred (aref vec m))
               (-1 (bin-search-aux l (+ l (floor (- m l) 2))))
               ( 0 m)
               ( 1 (bin-search-aux m (+ m (floor (- m l) 2)))))))
    (bin-search-aux 0 (floor l 2)))))
```

Test:

```
CL-USER > (bin-search #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
                      (lambda (x)
                        (if (< x 7) 1 (if (> x 7) -1 0))))
6
```

Comment: (bin-search #(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) (lambda (x) (if (< x 7) 1 (if (> x 7) -1 0))))

returns 6, as it should.

Comment: There's no condition to stop searching if no match exists.